# I am trying to echo an alert when input field was empty, but it alway echo alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress login. I am trying to call a function when the login or password input was empty. I am trying the following code, no matter I enter something into the input or nothing, it always echos alert, why?

I know inside input, `value=""`, means nothing before I enter anything, even if I enter something, on the console, I still see the `value=""`, I am confused now.

```js
var user_login = $('#user_login').val();
var user_pwd = $('#user_pass').val();
$('#wp-submit').click(function() {
  if (user_login == '' || user_pwd == ''){
    alert('hello');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="user_login" type="text" value="" name="log"></input>
<input id="user_pass" type="text" value="" name="pwd"></input>
<input id="wp-submit" type="submit" value="log in"></input>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only getting the value on first pageload, not when the button is clicked.

You have to get the value inside the click handler

```
$('#wp-submit').click(function(){
    var user_login = $('#user_login').val();
    var user_pwd   = $('#user_pass').val();

    if (user_login === '' || user_pwd === ''){
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```